# Is the rstoolbox package suitable for the GF-1 satellite?

Tags: r

I want to use the rstoolbox package to complete the classification of GF-1 remote sensing, but there are many problems. Because I am a beginner, I can’t even understand when rstudio reports an error. I would be very grateful if you could provide some advice on how to understand error messages or how to learn R.

the code

```
    input <- raster("D:/rs/xxx.dat")
    set.seed(25)
    unC <- unsuperClass(input, nSamples = 100, nClasses = 5, nStarts = 5)
    table(unC$class)
```

These are some of the errors I get running：

```
< table of extent 0 >
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you need a beginner's course to understand the basics.  There are many free ones available online - a simple google search should find some.  Once you have a grasp of what's going on you will be able to identify a specific issue to ask about here.